# dplyr match variable with multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a quite large data frame containing among others two columns: towns and counties, and a bunch of lines corresponding to combinations of the two. I would like to get a new column with a unique ID for every combinations. I could probably do it in base R, but I am trying to convert to `dplyr` for this project.

The following code gives me an ID for each combination of two variables in the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

dd <- data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:10], 100, TRUE), y = sample(letters[1:10], 100, TRUE))


id <- dd %>% distinct(x, y) %>% mutate(1:n())
```

How can add this `id` variable back to `dd` in the correct positions?

Comment: Try `left_join(dd, id)`

Comment: A little hacky, but maybe easier: `dd %>% mutate(id = as.integer(factor(paste(x, y))))`

Comment: Or another way of writting @alistaire's suggestion: `dd %>% mutate(id=as.numeric(interaction(x,y)))`

Comment: Related to this github issue: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1185